# Why minimum per page products (9) are not displaying in frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Why does the products rendering into frontend, restricts to only few products, even though i have more than 20 products, i get only 7 products rendered.

My pager limit is set for mim of 9 products, but only 7 is displaying, but i can access the other products in next page.

Is it problem in my pager or the controller?

Cleared cache, reindexed, enabled developer mode, i dont get any logs as well!

Answer (score 0):

Check your product status, website, store, quantity.

If everything is okay then try reindexing.

From Admin: `System -> Tools -> Index Management`

From command line: `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Comment: Its reindexed and cache cleared, in one of my custom module, its rendering, but not in my another custom module... i dont get any logs as well, enabled though and im in developer mode